# Incorrect syntax near 'db_cursor'

Tags: sql, cursor

I am getting the 'Incorrect syntax near 'db_cursor' error when attempting to run the below query. Can someone please tell me why and where my error in the scripting? Thanks in advance!

```
declare @Sort varchar(4000) 
declare @OpenDate datetime
declare @ret int;

     set @Sort = 'All'
     set @OpenDate = '1/1/2015'

     IF (@Sort = 'All') 
        BEGIN
            declare @Organization varchar(2500)
            declare @OrgEmp int         

            Set @OrgEmp = 0
            Set @ret = 0

declare db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
     SELECT distinct RTrim(Organization) + '|' as Oganization,
           (select rpt.ufnGetEmployeePopulation(RTrim(Organization)  + '|',  @OpenDate)) as NumberofEmployee FROM dbo.CorpStartEndDates where EndDate >= @OpenDate 

    OPEN db_cursor   
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @Organization, @OrgEmp   

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
    BEGIN   
        Set @ret = @ret + @OrgEmp

        FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @Organization, @OrgEmp   

         END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an END

if the cursor is inside the first BEGIN/END then put END after the DEALLOCATE

If the cursor is outside of the first begin/end, but the end before the OPEN

so..

```
    declare @Sort varchar(4000) 
    declare @OpenDate datetime
    declare @ret int;

    set @Sort = 'All'
    set @OpenDate = '1/1/2015'

    IF (@Sort = 'All') 
    BEGIN
        declare @Organization varchar(2500)
        declare @OrgEmp int         

        Set @OrgEmp = 0
        Set @ret = 0

        declare db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
        SELECT distinct RTrim(Organization) + '|' as Oganization,
       (select rpt.ufnGetEmployeePopulation(RTrim(Organization)  + '|',  @OpenDate)) as NumberofEmployee FROM dbo.CorpStartEndDates where EndDate >= @OpenDate 

        OPEN db_cursor   
        FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @Organization, @OrgEmp   

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
        BEGIN   
            Set @ret = @ret + @OrgEmp

            FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @Organization, @OrgEmp   

        END   

        CLOSE db_cursor   
        DEALLOCATE db_cursor 
    END
```

or

```
 IF (@Sort = 'All') 
    BEGIN
        declare @Organization varchar(2500)
        declare @OrgEmp int         

        Set @OrgEmp = 0
        Set @ret = 0
    END
```